# Finding the difference between two lists

Tags: .net, vb.net, hash, equality

In my current project I'm trying to compare two lists of objects, finding out if objects have been added, removed, changed or stayed the same.

I'm leveraging `IEnumerable.Except` for this as follows:

```
Dim newOnes = current.Except(previous, equalityComparer).ToList
Dim removedOnes = previous.Except(current, equalityComparer).ToList()
Dim existingOnes = current.Except(newOnes, equalityComparer).ToList
Dim changedOnes = existingOnes.Except(previous, changedComparer).ToList()
Dim unchangedOnes = existingOnes.Except(changedOnes, equalityComparer).ToList()
```

For this I have to implement IEqualityComparers.
Finding out if a pair of objects has changed in property values (changedOnes), requires I write a 'changedComparer' which is an IEqualityComparer that checks on non-identity-defining-fields (such as member collections).

As the Except method apparently first checks the GetHashCode and doesn't go to the Equals method if the hashes are equal, my setup falls apart.

I'm currently solving this as follows:

```
Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As Family) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Family).GetHashCode
    Dim hashCode As Long = 17
    If obj.ClientCode IsNot Nothing Then hashCode = CInt(((hashCode * 397) Xor obj.ClientCode.GetHashCode()) Mod Integer.MaxValue)
    ' SNIP a bunch more property fields
    If obj.Members IsNot Nothing Then hashCode = CInt(((hashCode * 397) Xor obj.Members.GetHashCode()) Mod Integer.MaxValue)

    Return CInt(hashCode Mod Integer.MaxValue)
End Function
```

Adding the hash of the Members list, always returns a different hash as it is checking the instance, not the content. This works for now, but off course removes all the advantages of having a hash.

**UPDATE**
What I'm looking for is **not** a better Equals method, but I question my entire methodology (maybe there is something OOTB, should I use a different interface). Failing that, how can I have a good GetHashcode when my property collection should be taken into account?

Answer (score 1):

I think [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) should do the trick, as it always uses the default equality comparer without requiring implementation of `IEqualityComparer`. The caveat though is that it also checks for order comparison.

Comment: I'm already using SequenceEqual in my Equals function. The issue resides in the GetHashCode() function.

Answer (score 1):

I use a `KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>` class that allows me to specify a key extracting lambda to detect any new or removed items.

I've implemented a [`ListDifference`](https://gist.github.com/sweko/7654887) (in C#, sorry) utility, that when given a `keyExtractor` and `comparer` spits out a list of new, deleted, changed and unchanged items. It does the obvious thing, i.e.

```
public ListDifference(IEnumerable<T> original, 
                      IEnumerable<T> updated, 
                      Func<T, object> keyExtractor = null, 
                      Func<T, T, bool> comparer = null)
{
  if (keyExtractor == null)
    keyExtractor = t => t;

  AddedItems = updated.Difference(original, keyExtractor);
  RemovedItems = original.Difference(updated, keyExtractor);

  var matches = from u in updated
                from o in original
                where keyExtractor(u).Equals(keyExtractor(o))
                select Tuple.Create(o, u);

  if (comparer == null)
  {
     //we are unable to detect changed items
    ChangedItems = null;
    UnchangedItems = matches;
  }
  else
  {
    ChangedItems = matches.Where(t => !comparer(t.Item1, t.Item2));
    UnchangedItems = matches.Where(t => comparer(t.Item1, t.Item2));
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks quite the same as what I did with my Comparer class with the difference that you're leveraging Funcs instead of a Comparers. For testability, I think I prefer to have to comparison logic in a comparer class.

Comment: Yes, this is basically the same thing, it's just encapsulated in a module that I know works, and it's shorted and more convenient to call.